# execCommand==null! when building intellij idea plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm getting the following error when trying to build 'runIde' profile in the gradle

Running from the tutorial here http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/build_system/prerequisites.html

```
08:18:04.614 [ERROR]
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
08:18:04.614 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
08:18:04.614 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
08:18:04.614 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
08:18:04.614 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':runIde'.
08:18:04.614 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > execCommand == null!
08:18:04.614 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
08:18:04.614 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
08:18:04.614 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. 
08:18:04.614 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] 
08:18:04.614 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED in 26s
08:18:04.614 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] 8 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 6 up-to-date
08:18:04.614 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService] Worker lease root.1 completed (0 worker(s) in use)
08:18:04.614 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Daemon worker: released lock on root.1
08:18:04.614 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Run build'
08:18:04.614 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.SynchronizedDispatchConnection] thread 19: dispatching class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.BuildEvent
08:18:04.614 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess] Releasing file lock for file content cache (C:\Users\saisr\IdeaProjects\mvn-refresher\.gradle\4.0\fileContent)
08:18:04.614 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache annotation-processors.bin (C:\Users\saisr\IdeaProjects\mvn-refresher\.gradle\4.0\fileContent\annotation-processors.bin)
08:18:04.614 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on file content cache (C:\Users\saisr\IdeaProjects\mvn-refresher\.gradle\4.0\fileContent).
08:18:04.630 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess] Releasing file lock for task history cache (C:\Users\saisr\IdeaProjects\mvn-refresher\.gradle\4.0\taskHistory)
08:18:04.630 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache taskHistory.bin (C:\Users\saisr\IdeaProjects\mvn-refresher\.gradle\4.0\taskHistory\taskHistory.bin)
08:18:04.630 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache fileSnapshots.bin (C:\Users\saisr\IdeaProjects\mvn-refresher\.gradle\4.0\taskHistory\fileSnapshots.bin)
08:18:04.630 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on task history cache (C:\Users\saisr\IdeaProjects\mvn-refresher\.gradle\4.0\taskHistory).
08:18:04.646 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.CachedStoreFactory] Resolution result cache closed. Cache reads: 2, disk reads: 1 (avg: 0.004 secs, total: 0.004 secs)
08:18:04.646 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.CachedStoreFactory] Resolution result cache closed. Cache reads: 0, disk reads: 0 (avg: 0.0 secs, total: 0.0 secs)
08:18:04.661 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.ResolutionResultsStoreFactory] Deleted 4 resolution results binary files in 0.014 secs
08:18:04.661 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess] Releasing file lock for Plugin Resolution Cache (C:\Users\saisr\.gradle\caches\4.0\plugin-resolution)
08:18:04.661 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache plugin-use-metadata.bin (C:\Users\saisr\.gradle\caches\4.0\plugin-resolution\plugin-use-metadata.bin)
08:18:04.661 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on Plugin Resolution Cache (C:\Users\saisr\.gradle\caches\4.0\plugin-resolution).
08:18:04.661 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess] Releasing file lock for Artifact transforms cache (C:\Users\saisr\.gradle\caches\transforms-1)
08:18:04.661 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on Artifact transforms cache (C:\Users\saisr\.gradle\caches\transforms-1).
08:18:04.661 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.workers.internal.WorkerDaemonFactory] Stopping 0 worker daemon(s).
08:18:04.661 [INFO] [org.gradle.workers.internal.WorkerDaemonFactory] Stopped 0 worker daemon(s).
08:18:04.661 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess] Releasing file lock for file hash cache (C:\Users\saisr\IdeaProjects\mvn-refresher\.gradle\4.0\fileHashes)
08:18:04.661 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache fileHashes.bin (C:\Users\saisr\IdeaProjects\mvn-refresher\.gradle\4.0\fileHashes\fileHashes.bin)
08:18:04.661 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache resourceHashesCache.bin (C:\Users\saisr\IdeaProjects\mvn-refresher\.gradle\4.0\fileHashes\resourceHashesCache.bin)
08:18:04.661 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on file hash cache (C:\Users\saisr\IdeaProjects\mvn-refresher\.gradle\4.0\fileHashes).
08:18:04.677 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.deployment.internal.DefaultDeploymentRegistry] Stopping 0 deployment handles
08:18:04.677 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.deployment.internal.DefaultDeploymentRegistry] Stopped deployment handles
08:18:04.677 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess] Cache Generated Gradle JARs cache (C:\Users\saisr\.gradle\caches\4.0\generated-gradle-jars) was closed 0 times.
08:18:04.677 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess] Releasing file lock for artifact cache (C:\Users\saisr\.gradle\caches\modules-2)
08:18:04.677 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache artifact-at-repository.bin (C:\Users\saisr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.23\artifact-at-repository.bin)
08:18:04.677 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache module-metadata.bin (C:\Users\saisr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.23\module-metadata.bin)
08:18:04.677 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache module-artifacts.bin (C:\Users\saisr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.23\module-artifacts.bin)
08:18:04.677 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on artifact cache (C:\Users\saisr\.gradle\caches\modules-2).
08:18:04.677 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild] The daemon has finished executing the build.
Cause: execCommand == null!
8:18:04 AM: Task execution finished 'runIde --debug'.
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess it is a bug of `gradle-intellij-plugin`, see this [issue](https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin/issues/273).I upgrade the version of `org.jetbrains.intellij` from `0.3.0` to `0.3.4` in `build.gradle` and solve the problem.